# change list of values to another list by changing its positon

Tags: java, android

I have a list1

i need to change it in  list 2 by alternative position

for Eg

> list2.add(0th postion of list2 (from), list1 9th position value)

is there any posiblity

Comment: You want to reverse in order?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after.  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this method [set(int i, E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

```
 E aux = list2.set(index,list1.get(otherIndex));
```

`aux` is the element previously at the specified position.

Note that aux is not more in list2, it will replaced.

Example :

```
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        list1.add("a");
        list1.add("b");
        list1.add("c");

        list2.add("d");
        list2.add("e");
        list2.add("f");

        String aux = list1.set(0, list2.get(2));

        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(aux); // aux is a now
```

Output will be : [f, b, c]
                  a

Comment: i tried it not working by 'List1.set(0,list2.get(i));'

Comment: @tryingtohelp what exactly do you need? this will replace in list2 in a specific position the value with the value in list1

Comment: @nachookk here u mention aux what it mean

Comment: @tryingtohelp if you read the link i gave you, you realized, i put it in the answer, `List1.set(0,list2.get(i))` -> your a putting in list1 index 0, the value in list2 in index i

Comment: @tryingtohelp i put an example..take care that list1 and list2 must have the same Type

Comment: yes both are in same type but u put aux i cant understand that

Comment: @tryingtohelp i update the example hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List list1 = //...
Collections.reverse(list1);
```

If you need to maintain the first list, create a copy, then reverse the copy.

```
List list2 = new List(list1);
Collections.reverse(list2);
```

Comment: i need it by changing value with position for eg list2 8th position value to list1 0th position value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse your list
you can do as follows

```
    List<String> list1=new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("a");
    list1.add("b");
    list1.add("c");
    list1.add("d");
    Collections.reverse(list1);
    System.out.println(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to have it in reverse order in the second list

Try

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("1");
    list1.add("2");
    list1.add("3");
    list1.add("4");
    list1.add("5");
    list1.add("6");
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=list1.size()-1;i>-1;i--)
    {
        list2.add(list1.get(i));
    }
```